# pii-network - acl permission- authorize/revoke access network but not to himself

Tags: acl, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer, access-rules

I'm using online Playground of Hyperledger Composer (https://composer-playground.mybluemix.net/).

I'm tring to modify acl file from "pii-network" example.

I would like to **have authorized access only if participant want to authorize another member and not himself**... How can I do it?
I did the following change to ACL file but it does not work as I expected (it authorize/revoke anyone and not anyone without himself):

```
rule AuthorizeAccessTransaction {
   description: "Allow all participants to submit AuthorizeAccess transactions"
   participant(p): "org.acme.model.Doctor"
   operation: CREATE
   resource(r): "org.acme.model.AuthorizeAccess"
   condition: (r.getIdentifier() != p.getIdentifier())
   action: ALLOW 
}
rule RevokeAccessTransaction {
   description: "Allow all participants to submit RevokeAccess transactions"
   participant(p): "org.acme.model.Doctor"
   operation: CREATE
   resource(r): "org.acme.model.RevokeAccess"
   condition: (r.getIdentifier() != p.getIdentifier())
   action: ALLOW
}
rule OwnRecordFullAccess {
   description: "Allow all participants full access to their own record"
   participant(p): "org.acme.model.Doctor"
   operation: ALL
   resource(r): "org.acme.model.Doctor"
   condition: (r.getIdentifier() === p.getIdentifier())
   action: ALLOW
}
rule ForeignRecordConditionalAccess {
   description: "Allow participants access to other people's records if granted"
   participant(p): "org.acme.model.Doctor"
   operation: ALL
   resource(r): "org.acme.model.Doctor"
   condition: (r.authorized && r.authorized.indexOf(p.getIdentifier()) > -1)
   action: ALLOW
}

rule SystemACL {
   description: "System ACL to permit all access"
   participant: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.Participant"
   operation: ALL
   resource: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.**"
   action: ALLOW
```

}

I followed instruction from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VTX-9VyO6OU&feature=youtu.be  and I changed the .acl file like I showed

Does anyone know what is the problem? What did I wrong?

I show also cto file here:

```
namespace org.acme.model

concept Specialization {
o String hospital
o String hospital_ward //reparto ospedaliero
o String city 
o String county
o String zip
o String field //campo medico di specializzazione
```

}

```
participant Doctor identified by username {
o String username
o String firstName
o String lastName
o Specialization specialization 
o DateTime dob optional
o String[] authorized optional
```

}

```
abstract transaction DoctorTransaction {
o String username
```

}

```
transaction AuthorizeAccess extends DoctorTransaction {
```

}

```
transaction RevokeAccess extends DoctorTransaction {
```

}

```
event DoctorEvent {
o DoctorTransaction doctorTransaction
```

}

Comment: Just some feedback. Posting all the ACLs, not just the relevant part, confuses people who might be able to help. Additionally, you could've posted your cto file as well for more information (especially since you have changed it).

Comment: You've said this does not work 'as expected'. It would help if you could describe what you expected and what you actually experienced. What part of the ACL is not working? ... and yes, please also post the relevant sections of your cto file(s).

Answer (score 0):

Use relationship as datatype for your authorized users.

```
participant Doctor identified by username {
o String username
o String firstName
o String lastName
o Specialization specialization 
o DateTime dob optional
--> Doctor[] authorized optional
```

Then use this function to check condition in permissions.acl

```
rule ForeignRecordConditionalAccess {
   description: "Allow participants access to other people's records if granted"
   participant(p): "org.acme.model.Doctor"
   operation: ALL
   resource(r): "org.acme.model.Doctor"
   condition: (
    r.authorized.some(function (doc){
      return doc.$identifier === p.$identifier;
    })
   )
   action: ALLOW
}
```